# Mysql Got the error...and did not run wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

Hi i am using Windows 7 and having wampserver installed in it. When i run the server now. Than it strike with this error in mysql_error.log. I dont understand how to fix it. pls help me to fix it. Also wamp is not working and show as "orange".

Also i am using Apache 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.16, and  Mysql 5.6.12
Here is error...

```
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-11 18:32:51 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-10-11 18:32:52 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-11 18:32:52 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-11 18:32:52 9224 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-10-11 18:32:52 9224 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-10-11 18:32:52 9224 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 23003102
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-10-11 18:32:53 9224 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: These are not error's thay are `[Note]` i.e. informational messages.

Answer (score 0):

These are not error's they are `[Note]` i.e. informational messages.

If the WampServer icon is Orange, then it is probably Apache that has not started.

Check what is using port 80 like so:

```
left click the Wampmanager icon ( thats the icon in the system tray ) -> Apache -> Services -> Test port 80
```

If it reports anything other that

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.?.?? (Win32) PHP/5.?.??
```

Where the version numbers match what you have installed then something else has captured port 80 and needs to be Uninstalled, reconfigured or disabled.